# Можно ли методы класса выносить в разные файлы

Tags: c#

Иногда класс содержит большое количество методов, свойств и прочего. Хотелось бы как-то это дело сделать более читаемым. На текущий момент пользуюсь

```
#region реализация интерфейса блаблабла
 //Какой-то перечень методов
#endregion
```

На мой взгляд было бы удобно, если бы некоторые методы можно было вынести в отдельный .cs файл.

Есть ли такая возможность?

Comment: Разумеется можно. Для этого существует модификатор класса partial https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wa80x488.aspx

Comment: @rdorn о Господи. Я думал почему-то, что это разделение вида и кода к нему. Оформите ответ, я закрою вопрос.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Разумеется можно. Для этого существует модификатор класса partial. Пример использования из [документации](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/wa80x488.aspx):

```
public partial class Employee
{
    public void DoWork()
    {
    }
}

public partial class Employee
{
    public void GoToLunch()
    {
    }
}
```

Активно используется визуальным дизайнером студии для разделения пользовательского кода разработчика и кода, генерируемого самим дизайнером.